# Jquery plugin for image slideshow support for all resolutions

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery

> ```
>      In my application i need to use some plugins for make the image
> ```
>
> slideshow like coinslider.But i needs
>   to use this plugin in all
>   resolution(i.e)1280*900,1024*768,800*600
>   etc by setting the width property of
>   the plugin as auto.Is there any plugin
>   available for support this features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this http://www.shadowbox-js.com/ is what you need.
The standard size of the lightbox like windows it opens is proportional to the navigator window size. ;)

I hope it helps you!

**Edit:**

This is the code of a shadowbox configured to autostart with automatical roll over:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="./shadowbox-3.0.3/shadowbox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./shadowbox-3.0.3/shadowbox.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    Shadowbox.init(
    {
        continuous: true,
        slideshowDelay: 2
    }, function() //make the auto start, if you dont want it, just remove this function
       {
            setTimeout(function() //give a little time to shadowbox to be initialized
            {
                $('#first_image').trigger('click');
            }, 50 );
       });

});
</script>
<a id="first_image" href="img_example_1.jpg" rel="lightbox[group]" style="display:none;">
    <img src="img_example_1.jpg" style="display:none;" />
</a>
<a href="img_example_1.jpg" rel="lightbox[group]" style="display:none;">
    <img src="img_example_1.jpg" style="display:none;" />
</a>
```

Oh! I made the imgs hidden, but there is no real need to do it. ;)

Comment: Hi Jayme,Thanks for your reply.And I need one which is automatically rolled over like a coin-slider.Is anyone avail with this features?

Comment: The shadowbox can automatically roll over.
I edited the answer, give a look. ;)